# Generators - Printing generated values

Tags: python, generator

Can someone please explain to me why there is a difference in printing my sequence generation between "with" and "without" a **for** loop?

```
def generation(x):
    i = 0
    while i < x:
        yield i
        i += 1

x = generation(10)
print("Print without for loop: " + str(x))

print("Print with for loop: ")
for j in x:
    print(j)
```

Comment: Generators are basically lazy iterators.

Comment: try `print("Print without for loop: ", *x)`

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1756096/understanding-generators-in-python

Answer (score 1):

Your first `print` prints the generator *object*.  Your second `print` invokes the generator, iterating through the yielded values.

This is much like the difference between printing the value of a function object (handle) and calling the function.

I think that you're perhaps misinterpreting the semantics of your first `print`.  To get the list of integers in that form, you'd need something that iterates through the generator:

```
print("Print as list")
print (list(generation(10)))
```

Comment: Just `list(generation(10))` works. There's no need for a list comprehension.

Comment: Good point.  I was trying to parallel OP's usage.  Now that I see it in print, the `list` operation is better.  Answer is upgraded.